# How to get LAST_VALUE in a SESSION window in FlinkSQL?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I am using session windows in Flink SQL (1.13).
Is there a way (must be in SQL, no UDFs etc.) to get the last value of a certain field (in other words: this would be a value at `window_end`)?
I was trying with:

```
SELECT user_account_id, 
       SESSION_START(request_timestamp, INTERVAL '30' MINUTE) AS window_start, 
       SESSION_END(request_timestamp, INTERVAL '30' MINUTE) AS window_end,
       LAST_VALUE(package)
GROUP BY SESSION(request_timestamp, INTERVAL '30' MINUTE), user_account_id
```

but I am getting error:

```
Could not find an implementation method 'merge' in class 'org.apache.flink.table.planner.functions.aggfunctions.LastValueAggFunction' for function 'LAST_VALUE' that matches the following signature:
void merge(org.apache.flink.table.data.RowData, java.lang.Iterable)
```

I guess that using window functions (`OVER(...)`) would not work here.
Any hints appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the answer that this is not supported yet.
A workaround would be to create a custom [user-defined aggregate function (UDAGG)](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/functions/udfs/#aggregate-functions) .
Apart from that, there is a new [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-24103) for that functionality.